# On win7 when import tensoreflow it shows "no module named_pywrap_tensorflow" after i do use the vc_redist

Tags: tensorflow

the redist(x86) is different from those answers provided before(x64).Is that the point?

Meanwhile it shows "Unless you are using bazel, you should try to import tensorflow from its source directory".But i didn't do that.

Comment: Does your comment about "the redist(x86)" mean that you have installed the x86 (i.e. the 32-bit) version of the Visual C++ redistributable, instead of the x64 (i.e. the 64-bit) version? TensorFlow is distributed as a 64-bit library, so it needs the 64-bit redistributable to be installed.

Comment: Duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module/43566463#43566463

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have Visual Studio Installed and that MSVCP140.DLL is on your computer AND in your PATH envVar. You shouldn't be building from source on Windows as it is not supported. I assume that you installed via pip?

Check for the DLL, VS, your PATH variables and, if that doesn't work, redownload the vc_redist_x64 version.

Failing that, uninstall Tensorflow and try again with `pip install tensorflow` or from a nightly. I had a similar issue and starting fresh seemed to help.